# node image cropping with fixed size

Tags: node.js, image

hello I am making node application in which I have one functionality that is cropping image user upload image set height and with and node will crop image accordingly but I want to set it fix size when compress image like after cropping the image size should be in between 20kb to 50kb and I have used "Jimp" to crop but the jimp not giving that facility to set image size fix some time it is 9kb something 70kb but i want to be in 20kb to 50 kb
so anyone know other node image cropper with image fix image size
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use the right tool [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations) helps in cropping or resizing the image just by params

```
cloudinary.image("lady.jpg", {transformation: [
  {width: 400, height: 400, gravity: "face", radius: "max", crop: "crop"},
  {width: 200, crop: "scale"}
  ]})
```

The **[quality](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#adjusting_image_quality) or Kb** of the image could be further manipulated as well

```
cloudinary.image("sample.jpg", {quality: 60})
```